# ssrs Ignoring variable which is not declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is my part of the query which i am using in the Dataset in SSRS2008

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(20) =  null;

Declare @curDATEFIRST as Integer = @@DATEFIRST;
SET DATEFIRST 1;

IF @a=0 AND @b>1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStartDate DateTime = (SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM UserManagerDates WHERE EmployeeID=@b ORDER BY StartDate DESC);
    IF @NewStartDate>@StartDate SET @StartDate = @NewStartDate;
  END
```

Question:
I was copying my query into dataset from ssms and when i hit refresh in dataset i only get prompted for `@a` and `@b` in define query parameters. Actually i wasn't even declaring `@startdate` so i was expecting `@startdate` variable in define query parameters tab.  What changes should i make to to get prompted for `@startdate` along with the other two variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `@startdate` parameter, it is supposed to be populated by SSRS instead of your query, that could be the reason you are not being prompted.

I think you want to use `@startdate` to populate `@NewStartDate`, if so try this:

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(20) =  null;
Declare @curDATEFIRST as Integer = @@DATEFIRST;
SET DATEFIRST 1;

IF @a=0 AND @b>1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStartDate DateTime =
      (SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM UserManagerDates
       WHERE EmployeeID=@b ORDER BY StartDate DESC);
    IF @NewStartDate>@StartDate SET @NewStartDate = @startdate;
  END
```

Comment: Thank you.I was looking everywhere and couldnt find solution